# How to reuse artifactory definition across gradle projects

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory

How to reuse artifactory definition across gradle projects, I don't want to declare this on every individual gradle project we have within the company which either creates a library or generates a Spring Boot App

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'https://mycompany.jfrog.io/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'maven'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        defaults {
            publications('mavenJava')
            publishBuildInfo = true
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishPom = true
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team' : 'core']
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The JFrog CLI can do this for you. It actually applies the Gradle Artifactory plugin for you.

Before we begin, please ensure that the `artifactory {...}` definition does not exist in your `build.gradle` file.
Now you can [install](https://jfrog.com/getcli/) the JFrog CLI using one of the available methods.
The easiest one is the cURL command:

```
curl -fL https://install-cli.jfrog.io | sh
```

You can run Gradle build with the JFrog CLI in 3 steps:

1. Configure your Artifactory server:

```
jf c add --url=https://mycompany.jfrog.io --user=<username> --password=<password>
```

2. Configure your Gradle project:

```
# Interactively in your machine, so you can commit the .jfrog/projects/gradle.yml file:
jf gradle-config

# Non-interactive:
jf gradle-config --repo-deploy=<resolution-repo> --repo-deploy=<deployment-repo> --use-wrapper
```

For advanced configuration, use `jf gradle-config --help` or read the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningGradleBuilds).

3. Run the build:

```
jf gradle clean artifactoryPublish
```

Read more:

- [QuickStart Guide: Maven and Gradle](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/QuickStart+Guide%3A+Maven+and+Gradle)
- [Getting started with JFrog using the CLI](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/blob/v2/guides/getting-started-with-jfrog-using-the-cli.md)